# efficient method to select index of vector in c++

Tags: c++

In C++, suppose you have a vector with `boolean` values, and you want to select randomly one index among those corresponding to True values.

What is the most efficient method to use?

**Example:**

```
vector<bool> v(4);
v.at(0)=true
v.at(1)=false
v.at(2)=true
v.at(3)=true
```

You want to select a number among the subset `{0,2,3}`.

I have so far tried 2 methods:

1. Stacking indexes in a vector and then selecting among these elements. Extremely slow.
2. Naive method: randomly select a index until `v.at(rnd_sel_index)` is `True`. Considerably faster.

Any suggestions faster than method 2?

Comment: you need to give more details: for example: are you going to select one index from the same vector several times?

Comment: How many times are you doing the operation? Does it make sense to store valid indexes somewhere else? Does the distribution have to be uniform?

Comment: I should think the most efficient approach will depend on the expected density of true values in the vector. Your naive method will be pretty efficient if you have a reasonably high density of true values.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps there's a more efficient approach.

Rather than storing what is there and what is not, perhaps it's better to store only what is not - i.e. a vector containing indices that are free.

the order of this vector can be easily randomised once, and you can then pull items from the `back()` until it's `empty()`.

When you want to return items to the 'free index pool', simply insert them in a random position in the vector.

Comment: Isn't this exactly OPs method 1 that they said was "extremely slow" in their case.

Comment: It didn't strike me that he was describing this since he didn't mention pre-randomisation. I would be stunned if it was 'extremely slow' unless the vector was larger than a small moon...

Comment: I expect it depends how many times you want to pick an index from a given vector. I did some quick testing and, if you are only picking once, OPs naive method 2 was much faster, even for quite sparse data.

Comment: yes of course (unless there are many more invalid positions than valid ones). However, if we're picking only once the case for any optimisation is a difficult one to make convincingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the well-known method for selecting an element from a sequence of unknown length.

Example Code:

```
#include <random>                                                                                      
#include <iostream>                                                                                    
#include <vector>                                                                                      
#include <algorithm>                                                                                   
std::size_t choose_element(const std::vector<bool>& v) {                                               
  auto last     = v.end();                                                                             
  auto chosen_i = std::find(v.begin(), last, true);                                                    
  auto i        = std::find(std::next(chosen_i), last, true);                                          
  double n      = 2.0;                                                                                 
  static auto random_generator = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};                                 
  while (i != last) {                                                                                  
    if (std::bernoulli_distribution(1.0 / n)(random_generator))                                        
      chosen_i = i;                                                                                    
    i = std::find(std::next(i), last, true);                                                           
    ++n;                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                    
  return std::distance(v.begin(), chosen_i);                                                           
}                                                                                                      
int main() {                                                                                           
  std::vector<bool> v = {true, true, false, true};                                                     
  std::vector<int> indexes(v.size());                                                                  
  const double N = 100;                                                                                
  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)                                                                              
    ++indexes[choose_element(v)];                                                                      
  for (auto& index : indexes)                                                                          
    std::cout << std::distance(indexes.data(), &index) << ": " << (index / N) << "\n";                 
  return 0;                                                                                            
}
```

This has predictable performance and only takes one pass through the data. Of course if you are taking multiple samples from the same vector it may be more efficient to restructure the data to a different format and then draw from that. Also, if nearly all of the elements are true, your method (2) might perform better in the average case.